# Uniform convergence of infinite sum with Dirichlet characters

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, dirichlet-series, exponential-sums

I would like to prove uniform convergence of function series like :

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}   \chi(n) f(nx)$$ where $\chi$ is a primitive character and $f(x)$ a function decreasing to zero in zero and infinity.

Typically: $$F(x)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}   \chi(n) n^2 x^2 e^{-nx}$$

On intervals $[\epsilon, \infty[$ with $\epsilon >0$ it is obvious that we have uniform convergence as for high $P$ we have a constant $M$, such that $\forall x>\epsilon$: $$|\sum\limits_{n=P}^{\infty}   \chi(n) n^2 x^2 e^{-nx}| \le M \sum\limits_{k=P}^{\infty}  n^2 \epsilon^2 e^{-n \epsilon }$$

But on $[0,\epsilon]$ it is less obvious... Thanks to twisted Poisson Summation formula applied with Dirichlet Character we know that $F(x)$ is well defined in zero with $\lim_{x \to 0} F(x) =0$ but what about uniform convergence ? (For info about twisted Poisson Summation formula [Extension of Poisson Summation formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144563/extension-of-poisson-summation-formula))

I tried to use Mellin transform to find a proof but I did not succesd yet. Any idea or reference on this subject?

Comment: Perhaps what you really need is locally uniform convergence on the positive line. Tthe point $0$ is like $\infty$, it is just the other end of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific series is not uniformly convergent on any interval of the form $[0,\delta]$. If it were, then it would be uniformly Cauchy on that interval; in particular, there would exist $P$ such that for all $M\ge N>P$ we would have
$$
\bigg| \sum_{n=N}^M \chi(n)n^2x^2e^{-nx} \bigg| < \frac12
$$
for all $x\in [0,\delta]$. However, we can take $M=N$ and $x=\frac1N$, yielding the single term $|\chi(N)e^{-1}|$ which is too large (for the infinitely many $N$ at which $\chi$ does not vanish).

This counterexample seems to generalize to any $f(nx)$ not identically zero, and uses very little about $\chi$ other than that $\limsup|\chi(n)|>0$.